# JQuery retrieve data attibute if exits, else get default value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to do it in long way, but is there any shortcut to do this

```
var imgwidth;
if ($(elment).attr('data-imgwidth') !== undefined) {
    // attribute exists
    imgwidth = $(elment).data('imgwidth');
} else {
    // attribute does not exist
    imgwidth = '640px'; //default value
}
```

I sometimes use

```
var imgwidth = $(element).data('imgwidth') || '640px';
```

But I'm not sure whether that always works. For example, it fails if the data attribute is a boolean.

Comment: For boolean it fails... for example my element has data-showthumbs = "false", in this case $(element).data('showthumbs') || true, will evaluate to true.

Comment: `var imgwidth = ($(element).data('imgwidth') !== undefined) ? $(element).data('imgwidth') : '640px';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to decrease the amount of space this simple computation takes, this is where [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) become your friend. However, in most use-cases it sacrifices the readability of your code. So take caution in trying to compress too much.

Here would be an example that pertains to what you need:

```
// Ternary returns one value if a statement is true, and another if false;
var imgwidth= $(".container").attr('data-imgwidth')?  $(elment).data('imgwidth') : "640px";
```

Answer (score 1):

Mobile ATM, can't give you an example.  But one suggestion would be to create your own jquery extension to wrap up your "normally used" code.

$.fn.betterAttr = function(){....}